# input$tableId_row_selected triggers twice on load

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm not asking for a solution, I'm asking for an explanation. Anyone knows why `input$tableId_rows_selected` triggers twice onload in the following example? I already found a solution, but I can't figure out why it happens.

```r-shiny
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDT(iris)

  observe({
    print(input$table_rows_selected)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

On first load of page, the console output is.

```
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: When the app is launched, `input$table_rows_selected` "does not exist" (like `input$anything`) so is null; then the table is rendered but no row is selected, so `input$table_rows_selected` "exists" but is null.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now why this "double" trigger doesn't happen for other inputs that don't result from rendering a table.